# Difficulties understanding Monad Transformers

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

I was hoping to get some helpful input on understanding Monad Transformers, and in relation to that, what happens using `do` notation. The example I am trying to understand is the following:

```
data ProtectedData a = ProtectedData String a

accessData :: String -> ProtectedData a -> Maybe a
accessData s (ProtectedData pass v) =
    if s == pass then Just v else Nothing


type Protected s a = MaybeT (Reader (ProtectedData s)) a

-- untangles the monad construction
run :: ProtectedData s -> Protected s a -> Maybe a
run ps psa = runReader (runMaybeT psa) ps

access :: String -> Protected a a
access pass = do
                -- ask :: ReaderT (ProtectedData a) Identity (ProtectedData a) 
                -- lift :: ... -> MaybeT (ReaderT (ProtectedData a) Identity) (ProtectedData a)  
                pd <- lift ask
                -- as i understand it: ask returns the value inside the thing.
                -- the left arrow actually applies the monad
                let v = accessData pass pd
                -- return :: Maybe a -> Reader (ProtectedData a) (Maybe a)
                MaybeT $ return v
```

As I understand it the `Protected` type describes some *protected* data, that is stored in a shared environment (`Reader`) and is of type `Maybe (MaybeT)`.

I am having problems with the type-variables `s` and `a`:

- Does `s` describe the string (password) of the protected data, and `a`
  the type of the protected data?
- Does `s` describe the type of the protected data, and if so, what does
  `a` describe?

In the function run:

```
run :: ProtectedData s -> Protected s a -> Maybe a
run ps psa = runReader (runMaybeT psa) ps
```

As I understand it, the `Reader` from inside `Protected` is run on the `ProtectedData`, to return the value.

This leaves only the function `access`:

```
access :: String -> Protected a a
access pass = do  
                pd <- lift ask
                let v = accessData pass pd
                MaybeT $ return v
```

Which is the one providing the most headache for me. First I am having issues grasping the effect and result.

- Is this function used to inject passwords and data into the `Reader`?
- Is it used to access data and fail if the wrong password is given?

Secondly I am having trouble understanding the first line

```
pd <- lift ask
```

- I understand, that `ask` is used to get access to the shared environment
  through the `Reader`, but why do I have to `lift` it to a `MaybeT` to get
  the actual value inside of it?

Answer (score 6):

> As i understand it the Protected type describes some "protected" Data

No. `Protected s a` should be seen as the type of a *program* that returns a value of type `a`. During the computation the program has read-only access to a secret value of type `s`, and only if it "knows" the proper password.

Such secret value, paired with its password, has type `ProtectedData s`.

> does s describe the type of the protected Data, and if so, what does a describe?

Yes. Here `a` is the, generic, type of the result of the program.

An an example, you can consider the case where the password is a `String` (it has to be, in your code the string type is hard-coded) and the secret value has type `s = Int`. Then you write a program which accesses the secret integer, and checks whether it's positive, returning a `Bool`. Here, `a = Bool`.

Note that I simplified the scenario a bit. Since we also use `MaybeT`, we are modelling a program that does not always return a value of type `a`, but that can also fail. A possible failure could be caused by using the wrong password. In such case, `MaybeT` roughly aborts the program in the middle of its execution.

The signature

```
access :: String -> Protected a a
```

is perhaps better understood if we write it as

```
access :: String -> Protected s s
```

showing that it is a helper function to access the secret value (or failing), given a password attempt. It is used as follows:

```
myProg :: Protected Int Bool
myProg = do
  v <- access "123456"  -- try accessing the protected int
  return (v > 0)
```

If the password is wrong, the above code will cause a failure (`run` will return `Nothing`)

```
> run (ProtectedData "actual password" 42) myProg
Nothing
```

If the password is correct, instead it will produce the right boolean:

```
> run (ProtectedData "123456" 42) myProg
Just True
```

Here `Just` means that the password was correct, and `True` indicates that the protected `Int` was positive.

Comment: Thank you, realizing to think of `Protected s a` as a Program with return type `a` accessing protected Data of type `s` really helped me understand the concept.
If i understand correctly this means i can even use other Monads in my Program:
`giveEven :: String -> Protected [Int] [Int]
giveEven s = do
    v <- access s
    return (filter even v)`

Comment: @Superschnitzel Your code is correct, but you are not really using `[]` as a monad there. You could, though, but it would be "orthogonal", so to speak. `s` can be any type, and that includes monadic ones, but those do not interfere with the main monad `Protected s`.